# Can't connect Mongo shell to Mongo Atlas M0 using mongodb+srv

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to my MongoDB Atlas Cloud cluster via the `mongo+srv` connection like so:

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-mhzdc.mongodb.net/test" --username myuser
```

I am getting this response:

```
DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "_mongodb._tcp.cluster0-mhzdc.mongodb.net": Undefined error: 0
try 'mongo --help' for more information
```

I am using the following version of Mongo client:

```
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v4.0.5
git version: 3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

I can't find any resolution online. Any ideas what's wrong? Is this a bug in the given version of the Mongo shell client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like bug 34117, still unresolved:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34117

To work around the bug check if you have a DNS resolver active on your notebook.
On windows:

```
ipconfig /displayDNS
```

to see the current DNS resolver cache.
You might even try to erase the cache with the command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and retry.
If you are working on linux ubuntu try the command:

```
named -v
```

to check if the DNS resolver software is already installed.
If not:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bind9 bind9utils bind9-doc bind9-host
```

to install the needed packages, then start the service:

```
sudo systemctl start bind9
```

and retry.

On Mac OSX, the command is:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I am on OSX, so I will add the command to flush the DNS on that OS as well.

Comment: DNS using Spectrum blocks srv requests to MongoDB Atlas.   I had to change my DNS servers to Google's 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 3):

The same happens to me, but just after i change my internet provider. Before, i could connect to mongo atlas with no problem.

I guess this happens because the DNS resolver of my internet provider could not resolve the uri to connect to mongodb atlas.

The Solution ->
Change de DNS resolver on my PC:

1. Open the Control Panel.
2. Click View network status and tasks
3. Click Change adapter settings on the left portion of the window.
4. Double-click the icon for the Internet connection you're using.
5. Click the Properties button.
6. Click and highlight Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and click Properties.
7. If not already selected, select the Use the following DNS server addresses option.
8. Enter the new DNS addresses and click OK and close out of all other windows.

I used google public dns 8.8.8.8.

After that i could connect again with my mongo shell ou compass to mongo atlas.

Hope that helps someone..

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem with Comcast Xfinity. For those running Ubuntu 18.04 or similar, I had to edit (you'll need root permissions) the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file, and add to following line:
`supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;`
I hope this helps somebody, took me too long to figure it out. :-)

Comment: DNS using Spectrum blocks srv requests to MongoDB Atlas.   I had to change my DNS servers to Google's 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

I spent lot of time to figure the out issue. after the change DNS it worked. thanks
Used google dns servers.

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4